# HTML seems to be trying to render a variable before it's initialized in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, get, render

The application works fine, but the console seems to display this error every alternate time I refresh:

GET http://localhost:4200/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
@   lists.component.html:3 (seems to reference 3rd line of html code below)

I reckon that HTML is trying to render the l.image variable before it's properly initialized via a GET request from a local SQL?

My application essentially uses Angular to query a node JS server, which returns an SQL query result. Thank you in advance.

Angular Code

```
export class ListsComponent implements OnInit {

  lists:any

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private cloud: Cloud, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.getImages()
   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  async getImages(){
    this.lists = await this.http.get<any>('/lists').toPromise()
  }
```

Node JS code

```
app.get('/lists', async (req, resp) => {
    const conn = await pool.getConnection()
    try {
        const [ result, _ ] = await conn.query(SQL_SELECT_ALL_FROM_LISTS)

        resp.status(200)
        resp.type('application/json').send(result)
    } catch(e) {
        console.error('ERROR: ', e)
        resp.status(500)
        resp.end()
    } finally {
        conn.release()
    }
})
```

HTML

```
    <li *ngFor = "let l of lists" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">

        <img *ngIf = "l.image !== 'undefined'" [src]="l.image" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" width="10%">
        
        <a (click) = "routeToTasks(l.listID, l.listName)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-primary">{{l.listName}}</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteList(l.listID)">Delete</button>    
    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using question mark just before using the dot operator as is shown below:

```
<li *ngFor = "let l of lists" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <img *ngIf = "l?.image !== 'undefined'" [src]="l?.image" class="img-thumbnail img-fluid" width="10%">
    <a (click) = "routeToTasks(l.listID, l.listName)" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action list-group-item-primary">{{l.listName}}</a>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteList(l.listID)">Delete</button>    
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering `<li *ngFor = "let l of lists" >` however `lists` is undefined at the start.

I would suggest either you specify `lists:any = []` so that there is an initial value and it won't render any child objects, or you could use the `async` pipe that will handle waiting for dynamic data:

```
<li *ngFor = "let l of lists | async" >
```

and remove the `toPromise()`from you function

```
async getImages(){
    this.lists = await this.http.get<any>('/lists')
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two thing you can do. Instead of calling `this.getImages()` from `constructor` call it from `ngOnInit` and wrap `li` inside `ng-content`

```
 <ng-content *ngIf="list">
      <li  *ngFor="let l of lists"
        class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
        <img *ngIf = "l.image !== 'undefined'" [src] = "l.image" class =
        "img-thumbnail img-fluid" width = "10%" > 
        <a (click) =
        "routeToTasks(l.listID, l.listName)" class = "list-group-item
        list-group-item-action list-group-item-primary"> {{l.listName}} </a> 
        <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger" (click) =
        "deleteList(l.listID)"> Delete </button> </li> </ng-content>
      </li>
</ng-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Angular` consider using `Observable`

In your code this can be changed into

```typescript
export class ListsComponent implements OnInit {
  lists:any[] = []; // Create an empty list

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private cloud: Cloud, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getImages.subscribe(lists => this.lists = lists)
  }

  getImages = () => this.http.get<any[]>('/lists')
  
}
```

Note the changes;

1. Changed `lists:any` to `lists:any[]` as we expect an array
2. changed the `getImages()` to `getImages = () => this.http.get<any[]>('/lists')`. Its a function that returns an `Observable`
3. Instead of using `async/await` we simply use `subscribe`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest is, add a ngIf directive to your html component and make the value as true once you get the response back from server.

```
<div *ngIf="displayDetails">

<li *ngFor = "let l of lists" 
...

</div>
```

In your component, once you get the response from the server make the make display details as true.

```
 displayDetails:boolean = false;

     this.getImages.subscribe(lists => {
    this.lists = lists ;
      this.displayDetails = true;
    )}
```